# Colors not displaying properly matplotlib bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to create a bar chart with one colour per bar.
Dataset: [Dataset Link](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/akshaydattatraykhare/car-details-dataset)

When I use the color parameter in a matplotlib bar chart, the colours do not assign one to each bar. They randomly distribute throughout all the bars, with no explicit pattern.

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Read file
df = pd.read_excel('CAR DETAILS FROM CAR DEKHO.xlsx')

#Change price column
df["price_sterling"] = df["selling_price"].apply(lambda x: x*0.011)

#PLOT BAR
plt.bar(df.owner,df.price_sterling,color=['red', 'yellow', 'black', 'blue', 'orange'])
plt.xticks(rotation="vertical")
plt.show()
```

[Bar chart output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik78w.png)

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

I have not seen this problem in any of the many tutorials and SO pages I have visited...

Comment: Maybe you want a count plot instead of just one little bar per entry? E.g. with seaborn: `sns.countplot(data=df, x='owner', y='price_sterling', palette=['red', 'yellow', 'black', 'blue', 'orange'])`?

Comment: Note that stackoverflow highly prefers questions with reproducible data and code.

Comment: I got an error using sns.countplot... but removed the " y='price_sterling' " and it worked! Thank you! P.S. This worked if you replace countplot with barplot. P.S.S. I have now edited my question. :) P.S.S.S. I would mark this as the correct answer, but it is only a comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it will depict the value of your df.price and df.owner in color randomly. I don't know what you're plotting to represent but what if you need to assign a color to each bar. Simply use **.set_color** for each bar as below example

```
 graph = plt.bar([1,2,3,4], [10,11,12,13])
 graph[0].set_color('red')
 graph[1].set_color('green')
 graph[2].set_color('orange')
 graph[3].set_color('blue')
 plt.show()
```

or another way

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [10, 11, 12, 13]
figure, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.bar(a, b, color=['red', 'green', 'orange', 'blue'])
```

I think you are trying to calculate the total "selling price" of the "owner"? If so then you can add the following

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Read file
df = pd.read_excel('CAR DETAILS FROM CAR DEKHO.xlsx')

#Change price column
df["price_sterling"] = df["selling_price"].apply(lambda x: x*0.011)
new_df = df.groupby(['owner']).sum()

#PLOT BAR
plt.bar(new_df.index,new_df.price_sterling,color=['red', 'yellow', 'black', 'blue', 'orange'])
plt.xticks(rotation="vertical")
plt.show()
```

Comment: When I copy your code, it works; but when I put in the columns of my dataset, it doesnt. I have edited my question to include the dataset and some more info, if that will help?

Comment: Sorry I still don't know what you want to plot (sum or mean of "selling_price" column). Please refer to the answer I edited.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not realise that I had no aggregation on my price column... That makes a lot of sense, thank you for your time!!